How can I align text outside of a wheelchart slice that is spread over various lines?
I would like to add additional text to the three slices in the way, that they are align like the text in the shape.
How do I align the sections of text to their appropriate position? Additionally I have a lot of text so I need to spread this over multiple lines.
This is my mwe:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{RWTHBordeaux100}{RGB}{161,16,53}
\definecolor{RWTHBordeaux25}{RGB}{229,197,192}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\a{30}
\def\b{12}
\wheelchart[
data sep=0.3,
gap=0.1,
inner data=\bfseries\sffamily\WCcount,
inner data sep=2-2*cos(\b),
inner data style={
  white,
circle,
fill=RWTHBordeaux100,
},
slices inner={ arc[
      start angle=\WCangle{1}{0}{0}{0},
      end angle=\WCangle{0.5}{\b}{0}{0},
      radius=\WCradius{0}{0}
] arc[
      start angle=\WCmidangle-90,
      end angle=\WCmidangle+90,
      radius=2*sin(\b)
] arc[
      start angle=
        \WCangle{0.5}{-\b}{0}{0},
      end angle=\WCangle{0}{0}{0}{0},
      radius=\WCradius{0}{0}
    ]
},
slices outer={
    arc[
      start angle=\WCangle{0}{0}{1}{0},
      end angle=\WCangle{0.5}{-\a}{1}{0},
      radius=\WCradius{1}{0}
    ]
    --(\WCpoint{0.5}{0}{1}{0.3})
    --(\WCpoint{0.5}{\a}{1}{0})
    arc[
      start angle=
        \WCangle{0.5}{\a}{1}{0},
      end angle=\WCangle{1}{0}{1}{0},
      radius=\WCradius{1}{0}
    ]
},
slices style={
  draw=RWTHBordeaux100,%\WCvarB,
  fill=RWTHBordeaux25,%\WCvarB!25,
  ultra thick
},
data=,
start half=90,
arc around text,
arc data=|\fontsize{15}{1}\selectfont\bfseries\sffamily|\WCvarA,
arc data pos=0.55,
arc data style={text color = RWTHBordeaux100},
value=1,
 arc data dir={\WCmidangle<181?1:-1}, % Direction of data (text) placement
 arc data pos={\WCmidangle<181?.6:.7},
        ]{%
  PAUSE,
  REFLECT,
  ASK
}
\path[
  decorate,
  decoration=
    { % Text going to "1 Pause"
      text along path,
      text=|\fontsize{5}{1}\selectfont\bfseries|{XXXXXXXXX\\ XXX XXX X X X X },
      text align=center,
      text color=black
    }
    ] (270:{2}) arc[start angle=270,end angle=-90,radius=2.7];
\path[
  decorate,
  decoration=
    { % Text going to "2 Reflect"
      text along path,
      text=|\fontsize{5}{1}\selectfont\bfseries|XXXX YYYY YY Y Y  YY  ,
      text align=center,
      text color=black
    }
    ] (270:{1}) arc[start angle=180,end angle=90,radius={3}];
\path[
  decorate,
  decoration=
    { % Text going to "3 Ask"
      text along path,
      text=|\fontsize{5}{1}\selectfont\bfseries|ZZZZZZZ ZZZZZ,
       text align=center,
      text color=black
    }
    ] (270:{1}) arc[start angle=-90,end angle=90,radius={3}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

And the results looks like:


The additional arc data are placed with an additional \wheelchart (of which I wrote the package with the same name). The positioning can be changed with the key arc data pos.
Since the key data is empty, the key data sep=0.3 is removed for code clarity.
Since there is no arc, the key arc around text does not apply and is removed for code clarity.
The key arc data pos was given twice. The first occurrence is removed.
The commands \bfseries\sffamily are placed in the beginning of the tikzpicture.
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\definecolor{RWTHBordeaux100}{RGB}{161,16,53}
\definecolor{RWTHBordeaux25}{RGB}{229,197,192}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\bfseries\sffamily
\pgfkeys{
  /wheelchart,
  arc data dir={\WCmidangle<181?1:-1},
  data=,
  start half,
  value=1
}
\def\a{30}
\def\b{12}
\wheelchart[
  arc data=|\fontsize{15}{1}\selectfont|\WCvarA,
  arc data pos={\WCmidangle<181?.6:.7},
  arc data style={text color=RWTHBordeaux100},
  gap=0.1,
  inner data=\WCcount,
  inner data sep=2-2*cos(\b),
  inner data style={
    white,
    circle,
    fill=RWTHBordeaux100
  },
  slices inner={
    arc[
      start angle=\WCangle{1}{0}{0}{0},
      end angle=\WCangle{0.5}{\b}{0}{0},
      radius=\WCradius{0}{0}
    ]
    arc[
      start angle=\WCmidangle-90,
      end angle=\WCmidangle+90,
      radius=2*sin(\b)
    ]
    arc[
      start angle=\WCangle{0.5}{-\b}{0}{0},
      end angle=\WCangle{0}{0}{0}{0},
      radius=\WCradius{0}{0}
    ]
  },
  slices outer={
    arc[
      start angle=\WCangle{0}{0}{1}{0},
      end angle=\WCangle{0.5}{-\a}{1}{0},
      radius=\WCradius{1}{0}
    ]
    --(\WCpoint{0.5}{0}{1}{0.3})
    --(\WCpoint{0.5}{\a}{1}{0})
    arc[
      start angle=\WCangle{0.5}{\a}{1}{0},
      end angle=\WCangle{1}{0}{1}{0},
      radius=\WCradius{1}{0}
    ]
  },
  slices style={
    draw=RWTHBordeaux100,
    fill=RWTHBordeaux25,
    ultra thick
  }
]{%
  PAUSE,
  REFLECT,
  ASK%
}
\fontsize{5}{1}\selectfont
\wheelchart[
  %arc data=|\unexpanded{\fontsize{5}{1}\selectfont}|\WCvarA,%This only applies the fontsize to the first line of text. Therefore, \fontsize{5}{1}\selectfont is placed above instead.
  arc data=\WCvarA,
  arc data expand=e,
  arc data pos{list}={1.45,1.5,1.4},
  slices style={fill=none}
]{%
  XXXXXXXXX\\XXX\\XXX X X X X,
  YYYY\\YYYY\\YY\\Y Y  YY,
  ZZZZZZZ\\ZZZZZ%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


